Hashtag symbol in Ruby on Rails string
I have a string in Ruby on Rails. This string contains a '#' character. The problem is that my program interprets this '#' as comment, but it is part of a password string. How can I handle this?
The file is the config file for GitLab
Here is a snippet from the SMTP configuration where I'm struggling.
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true  
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.xxx.com" 
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "abc@xxx.com"  
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "X#X" #<-- This is the problem in the gitlab.rb file  
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "xxx.com" 
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"  
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'abc@xxx.com'   
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'abc@xxx.com'  
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true  

I've tried '\#', tested the '%23', ...

Please post some actual code so that we can understand what is going wrong for you.

There is nothing notably wrong with what you have posted. Why do you believe this is being treated as a comment? Can you provide an error or a stacktrace or even a symptom (although preferably one of the first 2)?

the errormessage i'm recieving is /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-smtp-0.3.3/lib/net/smtp.rb:1088:in check_auth_response': 535 5.7.8 Authentication failed: wrong user/password (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)`. I've tested it with another password from another smtp without a '#' symbol and here it works fine.

While posting the stacktrace would certainly improve the post. The error is simply an authentication failure. This means there is nothing wrong with the actual code and nothing is interpreting your # as a comment. You will need to determine why that username and password is not working (maybe they are incorrect) but the code itself is fine.
